# Why is my PUT request not working in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, postman

It doesn't work of PUT requests in Flutter so I know it isn't a problem serverside, I checked with Postman and server side is working very well.

My raw data :

[image]

My send method to the server:

```
  Future<void> addProductType(
      {required String productID,
      required String title,
      required String description,
      required String isAvailable,
      required String status,
      required List<ModelTypeProduct> typeProduct}) async {
    String token = await getToken();


    var _body = <String, dynamic>{
      "title": title,
      "description": description,
      "is_available": isAvailable,
      "status": status,
      "product_types": typeProduct
    };
    print('sss -> ${jsonEncode(_body)}');

    final url = Uri.parse(url.config);

    final response = await http.put(
      url,
      body: jsonEncode(_body),
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      },
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('Hata: ${response.statusCode}');
    } else {
      print('Hata: ${response.statusCode}');
    }
  }
```

My logcat:

[image]

I don't know but I try to do it but unfortunately not successful for find best way, and I did just  write top code and not find out why doesn't send .

Comment: This isn't a solution, but just wondering why you have the ```if (response.statusCode == 200)``` condition when you print ```'Hata: ${response.statusCode}``` regardless of the condition.

Comment: just i set a name that shows in my log that the response is a 200 status code or error

Comment: The body is not properly encoded. As you can see in your logcat image, the list of product_types.

Comment: so I don't know where is code it is not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this issue, I have some 3 options for try to solve.

If you confirmed server side functionality, issues can throw from Flutter code, so you can check your **Request Body Formatting** and **Headers and Authorization**, and **Debugging the Request**. that was my solutions for solve this issue.

1. Request Body Formatting:
   you should confirm the `typeProduct` list is being serialized properly. check if the structure match to your server expects.
2. Headers and Authorization:
   verify your given token is valid and has the necessary permission for the update operation.

3.Debugging the Request:
you can print the url and complete request before sending it, so then you can find your issues if you have.

and I updated your code like bellow, so your can try it,

```
Future<void> addProductType({
  required String productID,
  required String title,
  required String description,
  required String isAvailable,
  required String status,
  required List<ModelTypeProduct> typeProduct,
}) async {
  try {
    String token = await getToken();

    var _body = <String, dynamic>{
      "title": title,
      "description": description,
      "is_available": isAvailable,
      "status": status,
      "product_types": typeProduct.map((product) => product.toJson()).toList(),
    };

    print('Your Request Body: ${jsonEncode(_body)}');

    final url = Uri.parse('http://app.shandizmive.ir/admin/api/v1/products/$productID');

    final response = await http.put(
      url,
      body: jsonEncode(_body),
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      },
    );

    print('Ypur Final Request URL: $url');
    print('Print your Response Status Code: ${response.statusCode}');
    print('Response Body: ${response.body}');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('Product Updated Successfully');
    } else {
      print('Failed to update this product. Status Code: ${response.statusCode}');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    print('Error: $error');
    // You can findout your exceptions in here.
  }
}
```